# How to add STDtime to a collection of processed NDVIs to later create a multidimensional dataset in arc

Tags: google-earth-engine, arcgis-pro, ndvi

I have prepared many annual NDVIs in GEE. but at this step to be able to use CCDC Change Analysis in ArcGIS Pro, my NDVIs need to have a dimension named STDtime which literally shows the acquisition time. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to provide more information or GGE code. Are annual NDVIs in one collection or as bands stacked in one image? Have you tried setting a property called `STDtime` with `.set()`? Can be used as filename? I use to set the filename with `col.set('system:index', date_index)` or `col.set('system:index', ee.String('prefix_').cat(date_index))`

Comment: Thanks so much @aldo_tapia. no my NDVIs are not in one collection since i had to use different processing on each image. I used Quality mosaic in GEE so at the the end of each code i have an annual composite NDVI. and no i have not tried .set(). does the code you provided work on a composite image?

Comment: It should work. If you're struggling while working with different years, take a look [on this code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ee832ce0bdaeb787d885e69c5722471a). I take day-of-year date and mosaic NDVI by DOY, you can adapt it for working by year. At the end, I download one scene by date with the filename as `id_year-doy.tif`. Easy for date extraction for later processing